# Prove $2^n > 1 + n \sqrt{2^{n-1}}$ for all $n > 2$

Tags: inequality

> Prove that $$2^n> 1 + n \sqrt{2^{n - 1}} \text{ for all } n > 2.$$

Comment: what exactly is your problem with this exercise?

Comment: Check it for $n=3$.  Then intuitively the left side doubles each time $n$ increases by $1$ while the right is multiplied by $\frac {n+1}n\sqrt 2 \lt 2$.  Can you convert that to an induction proof?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=3$, you have $2^3=8$, and $1+3\sqrt{2} \leq 1 + 3 \times 1,5 = 5,5$ so the statement is true.

Let's suppose that you have 
$2^n > 1 + n \sqrt{2^{n-1}}$ for an integer $n \geq 3$. Then 
$$2^{n+1} > 2 + 2n \sqrt{2^{n-1}} = 2 + \sqrt{2}\times n\sqrt{2^n} > 1 +   \sqrt{2}\times n\sqrt{2^n}$$

And for all $n > 2$, you have $$n > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1}$$ so $n \sqrt{2} > n+1$, so you deduce
$$2^{n+1} > 1 + (n+1) \sqrt{2^n}$$

and you are done.

Comment: It is simply said to use principles of inequalities it's not specified which prove this problem!

Comment: @ShashwatSharma What do you mean ?...